# How to avoid decimal points in SQL instead of round of value?

Tags: sql

Instead of rounding off the value and avoiding decimals, Is there any other way to make it only whole value.

Comment: cast to `integer` if you don't want to round off and top drop decimals

Comment: You can define a variable is `INT` and make an assignment like `SET @MyINTVariable = @MyFLOATVariable + 0.5'`. The `0.5` will take care of rounding to the nearest (i.e. `22.49` will yield `22` whereas `22.51` will yield `23`).

Answer (score 0):

Your use case sounds like the `FLOOR()` function, which 'truncates' a number by removing all decimal values from the result:

```
SELECT FLOOR(1.9999999)
```